# Save 4 lists as sublist elements in 1 list

Tags: r, statistics

I have `3 lists` each list has the same length. `List A`, `List B` and List `C`.

The datatypes of `B` and `C` are the same datatype(numeric) of list `A` is String.

I want to create a List `allList` with `4 subelements`:

```
> allList

[1]
[[1]] first element of A [[2]] first element of B [[3]] first element of C [[4]] Substraction of B and C

[2]
ect.
```

How can I implement that in R I would appreciate any idea!

**UPDATE**

Here is a concrete example:

```
    eventStudyList120_After <- list(eventWindow_120After_DateList, eventWindow_120After_DateList, eventWindow_120After_CDaxReturnList)

> (eventStudyList120_After)
[[1]]
  [1] "25.08.2009" "26.08.2009" "27.08.2009" "28.08.2009" "31.08.2009"
  [6] "01.09.2009" "02.09.2009" "03.09.2009" "04.09.2009" "07.09.2009"
 [11] "08.09.2009" "09.09.2009" "10.09.2009" "11.09.2009" "14.09.2009"
 [16] "15.09.2009" "16.09.2009" "17.09.2009" "18.09.2009" "21.09.2009"
 [21] "22.09.2009" "23.09.2009" "24.09.2009" "25.09.2009" "28.09.2009"
 [26] "29.09.2009" "30.09.2009" "01.10.2009" "02.10.2009" "05.10.2009"
 [31] "06.10.2009" "07.10.2009" "08.10.2009" "09.10.2009" "12.10.2009"
 [36] "13.10.2009" "14.10.2009" "15.10.2009" "16.10.2009" "19.10.2009"
 [41] "20.10.2009" "21.10.2009" "22.10.2009" "23.10.2009" "26.10.2009"
 [46] "27.10.2009" "28.10.2009" "29.10.2009" "30.10.2009" "02.11.2009"
 [51] "03.11.2009" "04.11.2009" "05.11.2009" "06.11.2009" "09.11.2009"
 [56] "10.11.2009" "11.11.2009" "12.11.2009" "13.11.2009" "16.11.2009"
 [61] "17.11.2009" "18.11.2009" "19.11.2009" "20.11.2009" "23.11.2009"
 [66] "24.11.2009" "25.11.2009" "26.11.2009" "27.11.2009" "30.11.2009"
 [71] "01.12.2009" "02.12.2009" "03.12.2009" "04.12.2009" "07.12.2009"
 [76] "08.12.2009" "09.12.2009" "10.12.2009" "11.12.2009" "14.12.2009"
 [81] "15.12.2009" "16.12.2009" "17.12.2009" "18.12.2009" "21.12.2009"
 [86] "22.12.2009" "23.12.2009" "24.12.2009" "25.12.2009" "28.12.2009"
 [91] "29.12.2009" "30.12.2009" "31.12.2009" "01.01.2010" "04.01.2010"
 [96] "05.01.2010" "06.01.2010" "07.01.2010" "08.01.2010" "11.01.2010"
[101] "12.01.2010" "13.01.2010" "14.01.2010" "15.01.2010" "18.01.2010"
[106] "19.01.2010" "20.01.2010" "21.01.2010" "22.01.2010" "25.01.2010"
[111] "26.01.2010" "27.01.2010" "28.01.2010" "29.01.2010" "01.02.2010"
[116] "02.02.2010" "03.02.2010" "04.02.2010" "05.02.2010" "08.02.2010"

[[2]]
  [1] 4.81 4.85 4.81 4.89 4.73 4.61 4.77 4.69 4.89 4.85 4.89 5.01 5.01 4.89 4.93
 [16] 4.93 4.93 4.97 5.01 5.01 4.93 4.93 4.93 4.93 5.21 4.93 5.41 5.21 5.25 4.97
 [31] 4.97 5.21 5.05 5.37 5.13 5.37 5.13 5.21 5.13 5.01 5.09 5.13 5.01 5.01 5.21
 [46] 5.21 5.21 5.41 5.37 5.33 5.33 5.21 5.21 5.21 5.17 5.09 5.17 5.81 6.21 7.81
 [61] 7.69 7.61 7.21 7.01 7.25 7.21 7.25 7.01 7.09 7.09 7.01 7.21 7.21 7.05 7.01
 [76] 7.01 7.05 7.21 7.21 6.97 6.89 6.97 6.69 6.53 6.33 6.65 7.05 7.05 7.05 7.05
 [91] 6.81 6.81 6.81 6.81 6.65 6.65 6.65 6.49 6.81 6.81 6.57 6.85 6.93 6.97 6.93
[106] 6.77 6.93 6.89 6.90 6.73 6.81 6.81 6.61 6.53 7.03 6.93 7.73 7.97 9.33 8.01

[[3]]
  [1]  0.62595516  0.89132960 -0.93323011  1.00388875  2.50655343  0.28025201
  [7]  0.04999239 -1.52822071 -1.48860354 -0.38646531 -1.54065680 -0.35443455
 [13] -0.54107231  0.15189458 -0.36811321 -1.31185921 -0.53398643  0.44765285
 [19]  0.81109101 -0.76254262  0.11309704  1.64429117  0.37294212 -2.59894035
 [25]  0.29588776  0.49762314  2.17220569  1.67482716 -0.79014302 -2.69996146
 [31]  0.18086490 -1.39072582  0.04210020 -1.14940251  1.16479551 -2.24208216
 [37]  0.41327193  1.54473332 -1.73781565  0.66416288 -0.27007314  1.26968917
 [43]  0.29432965  1.73758937  0.38854011  2.72671890 -1.76846884  2.95523593
 [49] -0.22681024  1.38835160 -1.83751398 -0.68721323 -0.26954741 -2.24083342
 [55]  0.39168239 -0.99082271  0.07924735 -0.34424802 -2.00230195  0.48655978
 [61] -0.21092848  1.55605852  0.71028798 -2.38596631  0.55334705 -0.54239847
 [67]  3.36386413 -1.28927630  0.98053264 -2.61935612 -0.11946242  0.17152317
 [73] -0.79343095  0.43919792  1.62169804  0.74055990 -0.99504492 -0.79728245
 [79] -0.73784636 -0.14656077 -1.42712116  0.95988962  0.22718293 -1.46958638
 [85] -0.21365446 -0.17256757 -0.59940253          NA          NA -0.22307263
 [91]  0.76736750  0.00000000 -1.50965723          NA  0.06111069 -0.13159651
 [97]  0.09545081 -0.32727619 -0.07225296  1.61131397 -0.40791980 -0.53016383
[103]  1.82016604 -0.62552046 -0.80490241  2.02857647  1.68204556  1.02683875
[109]  0.96765669 -0.57603687  0.50990350  1.64994011 -1.13511086 -0.82206204
[115] -1.03993428  0.61692305  2.53012795  1.96223075 -0.76549820 -0.34391479
```

I want to have:

```
[[1]]
[1]
"The Date for example "25.08.2009" "

[2]
4.81

[3]
0.62595516

[4]
Result of 4.81 - 0.62595516

[[2]]ect.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a `data.frame`?  They are designed for holding vectors of different types (note your sub-lists are not actually lists, they are vectors):

```
listA <- letters
listB <- runif(26)
listC <- runif(26)

data.frame(listA, listB, listC, sub=listB - listC)

#    listA      listB      listC         sub
# 1      a 0.93721137 0.69877094  0.23844043
# 2      b 0.42868786 0.11791925  0.31076861
# 3      c 0.47081416 0.53145039 -0.06063623
# 4      d 0.13014486 0.75029689 -0.62015202
# 5      e 0.26617170 0.47345083 -0.20727913
# 6      f 0.10516975 0.76087922 -0.65570947
# 7      g 0.73466382 0.99197147 -0.25730764
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

like so?

```
> list(listA, listB, listC)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 5 6 7


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 3 4 5


> do.call(list, lapply(c(listA, listB, listC), unlist))
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 5 6 7

[[3]]
[1] 3 4 5
```

EDIT, I meant `unlist` don;t know what I said `unclass` but both will work